# SSH proxy like NGINX Proxy Manager forward ssh session to correct server

Tags: ssh, proxy, forwarding

for my webserver i have one public IP which is determining on one server - the nginx proxy manager is handling the connection & forwarding to the correct server which only has an public ip.

Is there any solution for SSH which works in a similar way based on the hostname?